# QAbstractItemModel->setItemData returns false when inserting Qt::UserRole

Tags: c++, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I have no idea why when I try to insert `Qt::UserRole` into `QTreeView` item it returns false always
but not when i enter `Qt::EditRole` 
this is the code:

```
void TreeVieweX::insertRow(QString& slink)
{
    QModelIndex index = this->selectionModel()->currentIndex();
    QAbstractItemModel *model = this->model();
    int iRowCount = this->model()->rowCount();
    if (!model->insertRow(iRowCount, index.parent()))
        return;

    QModelIndex child = model->index(iRowCount,0, index.parent());
    bool bEditRole =  model->setData(child, QVariant(slink), Qt::EditRole); // working great can fetch the data later 

    QHash<QString, QVariant> indexSelectedMap;
    indexSelectedMap.insert("site_name",QVariant(slink));

    QMap<int, QVariant> roles;
    roles.insert(Qt::UserRole,indexSelectedMap);
    bool bUserRole =  model->setItemData( index.parent(),roles); //returns false , cant fetch data later
}
```

Answer (score 1):

QAbstractItemModel::setItemData is simply a convenience function which calls setData for each item in the roles map.

```
bool QAbstractItemModel::setItemData(const QModelIndex &index, const QMap<int, QVariant> &roles)
{
    bool b = true;
    for (QMap<int, QVariant>::ConstIterator it = roles.begin(); it != roles.end(); ++it)
        b = b && setData(index, it.value(), it.key());
    return b;
}
```

Assuming your model doesn't reimplement setItemData, the problem is probably in whatever implementation of setData you have in the concrete model.

Comment: I have had an issue with this implementation when dealing with drag/drop, **_note_ that setData is only called if b is true**.

The roles Map populated by the default drag/drop implementation contained data for roles that I didn't want to set into my model "DisplayRole, TooltipRole, etc so returning false for those would prevent the others in the map from being processed. At the end I had to override the setItemData method in my model to just handle the roles I cared about (EditRole, CheckStateRole).

Comment: Could you give an example of what can go wrong with setData in the concrete model?